# ESLint: Definition for rule 'jest/valid-describe' was not found. (jest/valid-describe)

Tags: jestjs, eslint

After upgrading eslint to 8, I got the following error on every test module:

```
 error  Definition for rule 'jest/valid-describe' was not found  jest/valid-describe
```

part of the `eslintrc.json` :

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "plugin:jest/recommended"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "import", "jest"],
  "env": {
    "jest/globals": true
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  // ...
}
```

and the packages versions are:

```
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/experimental-utils": "^4.28.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^25.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-testing-library": "^5.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.4",
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule was renamed to `valid-describe-callback` in `eslint-plugin-jest@25.0.0`, which you updated past. You will need to rename any config which references the old rule.

See
valid-describe: rename to valid-describe-callback (f3e9e9a)
https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/releases/tag/v25.0.0